# How do I delete a view within Task List?

Tags: task-list

I want to delete a view called Attachments within a Task List. Where do I go again to do that?

I also get the following error when I click on the Attachments view. Please see below. By the way, it is called an Attachments VIEW, right?
 [image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the List tab in the ribbon and click on List Settings. On the resulting page, scroll down a bit until you see the Views section. Click on the name of the view and you can delete it.

If that doesn't work, you can try opening the site in SharePoint Designer and deleting it from there.